# How get numbers from string (C#)

Tags: regex, numbers

I have the following string:

```
{ (MerchantId eq 5 or MerchantId eq 19 or MerchantId eq 34)}
```

I need to get as result an array of numbers:

5

19

34

I can't find the necessary regex expression for this action.
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
string input = "{ (MerchantId eq 5 or MerchantId eq 19 or MerchantId eq 34)}";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)");
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

var matches = regex.Matches(input);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(Int32.Parse(matches[i].Value));
}
```

If you insist on arrays use this instead:

```
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
int[] numbers = new int[matches.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Int32.Parse(matches[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks yo so much! List is valid too!